# Alternating Random Series Sum To \$N\$

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, random

## Challenge

Given a positive integer \$N  \ge 3\$, generate an alternating series of \$N\$ random numbers within the range \$[1, N]\$, such that their sum equals \$N\$. Expressed mathematically as

$$N = \sum_{i=1}^{N} (-1)^{i-1} a_i$$ where \$a_i \in [1,N]\$ are random terms.

**Input**

\$N\$

**Output**

A string representing the alternating series of \$N\$ terms (each prefixed by \$+\$ or \$-\$) that sum up to \$N\$.

**Notes**

Random numbers can be generated using any standard random number generation function. For example, `rand()` in C, `random.randint()` in Python, `Math.random()` in Javascript, etc.,...

## Examples

| N | alternating series |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | +1-1+3 |
| 4 | +4-1+3-2 |
| 5 | +4-2+4-4+3 |
| 6 | +5-1+4-4+3-1 |
| 7 | +6-1+4-7+4-1+2 |
| 8 | +6-7+7-5+7-1+2-1 |
| 9 | +3-7+8-3+2-8+9-2+7 |
| 10 | +10-4+4-2+8-3+1-4+5-5 |
| 11 | +11-7+1-2+2-10+3-5+10-2+10 |
| ... | ... |

Comment: "Alternating" needs to be better defined within the spec here.

Comment: Do the outputs have to be equally likely?

Comment: [Saying you should produce one or several outputs randomly without further specification](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10909/92727) is one of the things to avoid when writing challenges, and IMO just saying that you have to use a uniform RNG with values in \$[1,N]\$ isn't enough - do you have to use the straightforward rejection sampling algorithm?

Comment: To solve the issue mentioned by xnor and Command Master, a simple solution could be requiring each possible output to have nonzero probability

Comment: Why is there a specific output format requirement? Couldn't we just return a list of positive integers, and specify how to interpret that? (For example "the signs are alternating with the last always being positive".)

Comment: I'm no maths guy, but if each term is equally selected in \$[1,N]\$, then as a whole, the outputs are also equally likely?

Comment: @vengy choosing each term uniformly and testing for correctness repeatedly will be biased towards some answers over others (although all valid solutions are still _possible_ outputs).

Comment: Note to self, avoid `random` type problems as they have strict requirements beyond simply calling a RNG. ;)

Comment: FWIW neither the number of possible outputs (`1, 0, 6, 10, 320, 1666, ...`) nor the number of possible outputs equivalent up to rearrangement (`1, 0, 4, 5, 50, 124, ...`) are in the [Online Encylopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṗḅ-⁼ɗƇ⁸XṚṭNƭ€”+
```

A full program that accepts a positive integer, \$n\$, and prints a possible alternating sum, in the given format, with \$n\$ terms with absolute values from \$[1,N]\$.

All possible outputs are equally likely.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9qZWxsef//4bmX4biFLeKBvMmXxofigbhY4bma4bmtTsat4oKs4oCdK////zY)**

#### How?

```
ṗḅ-⁼ɗƇ⁸XṚṭNƭ€”+ - Main Link: positive integer, n
ṗ               - {[1..n]} Cartisian power {n}
                   -> all length n lists formed of values [1..n]
     Ƈ          - keep those for which:
    ɗ ⁸         -   last three links as a dyad - f(potential, n)
  -             -     literal -1
 ḅ              -     convert {potential} from base -1
                       -> last - penultimate + antepenultimate - ...
   ⁼            -     equals {n}?
       X        - uniform choice
        Ṛ       - reverse
            €   - for each:
           ƭ    -   alternate between:
         ṭ   ”+ -     a) tack to '+'; and
          N     -     b) negate
                - implicit, smashing print
```

Comment: \$[3,6]\$ run quicky, but \$7\$ onwards are really slow. Is that a result of the language? Thanks.

Comment: That is mostly a result of the implementation, it is first getting all \$n^n\$ possible arrays of \$n\$ numbers from the alphabet \$[1,n]\$. This is golf :)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 74 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,i,s)=>i^n?f(n,-~i,[s]+"+-"[i&1]+-~(Math.random()*n)):eval(s)-n?f(n):s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjTydTp1jT1i4zLs8@DcjTrcvUiS6O1VbS1lWKzlQzjNXWrdPwTSzJ0CtKzEvJz9XQ1MrT1LRKLUvM0SjW1AVr0rQq/p@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrpGmYaypyYUqYoIhYqqp@R8A)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (               // f is a recursive function taking:
  n,                //   n = input
  i,                //   i = counter, initially undefined
  s                 //   s = output string, initially undefined
) =>                //
i ^ n ?             // if i is not equal to n:
  f(                //   do a recursive call:
    n,              //     pass n unchanged
    -~i,            //     increment the counter
    [s] +           //     append to s ...
    "+-"[i & 1] +   //     ... either "+" or "-" according to
                    //     the parity of i
    -~(             //
      Math.random() //     followed by a random integer
      * n           //     in [1, n]
    )               //
  )                 //   end of recursive call
:                   // else:
  eval(s)           //   evaluate the expression
  - n ?             //   if the result is not equal to n:
    f(n)            //     try again
  :                 //   else:
    s               //     stop and return it
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 120 bytes

```python
from random import*
def f(n):
 while sum(L:=[s*randint(1,n)for s in(1,-1)*n][:n])-n:1
 return''.join('%+d'%v for v in L)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBCsMgEEX3nmI2QSdtCpJNEXKD3CBkUUgkljrKaFJ6equrz4P3fvzlI9D4jFyK5eCBX7TVcT4Gzr3YdgtWERoB38N9dkinV7OZltQ301FW@k5oA0MCRxUGjT2ti6EVBzJaAO/5ZJLy8Q5VkN1tk90FrbhqATOWyO3HqhGx/AE)

Brute-force method. Generates a list of \$N\$ random numbers until their sum is equal to \$N\$.

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 154 bytes

Assuming \$n\$ is in \$A1\$

```cpp
=LET(F,LAMBDA(F,LET(o,JOIN(,MAKEARRAY(A1,1,LAMBDA(i,_,IF(MOD(i,2),"+","-")&RANDBETWEEN(1,A1)))),IF(A1=SORTN(QUERY(,"select "&MID(o,2,99))),o,F(F)))),F(F))
```

Recursive formula that generates a random sequence. If the sum is \$n\$, it returns it, otherwise it generates a new sequence and the process is repeated.

Comment: Looks like it works most of the time for the range [3,35], but higher values give an error.

Comment: I believe changing `99` to `LEN(o)` should fix the logic of the formula and maybe the error too. But performance-wise it's still going to be pretty bad.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
L¤ãε(2Å€Ä'+ì]ʒOQ}ΩJ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9vc2FiaWX//0zCpMOjzrUoMsOF4oKsw4QnK8OsXcqST1F9zqlK//81) or [verify all possible results for a given input](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9vc2FiaWX//0zCpMOjzrUoMsOF4oKsw4QnK8OsXcqST1F9Sv//NQ).

`ε(2Å€Ä'+ì]` could alternatively be `` ε'+ìι`(.ι} `` for the same byte-count:

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9vc2FiaWX//0zCpMOjzrUnK8OszrlgKC7OuX3Kkk9Rfc6pSv//NQ) or [verify all possible results for a given input](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9vc2FiaWX//0zCpMOjzrUnK8OszrlgKC7OuX3Kkk9RfUr//zU).

**Explanation:**

```python
L             # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input]
 ¤            # Push its last item (without popping): the input
  ã           # Cartesian product to have all possible input-sized lists
   ε          # Map over each inner list:
    (         #  Negate all values
     2Å€      #  Then for every 2nd item (0-based index is divisible by 2):
        Ä     #   Absolute value to make the negative value positive again
         '+ì '#   Prepend a "+" instead
   ]          # Close both the every and outer maps
    ʒ         # Filter:
     O        #  Sum the values in the list together
      Q       #  Check whether this is equal to the (implicit) input-integer
    }Ω        # After the filter: keep a random inner list
      J       # Join it together to a single string
              # (which is output implicitly as result)

   ε          # Map over each inner list:
    '+ì      '#  Prepend a "+" before each value
       ι      #  Uninterleave the list into two parts
        `     #  Pop and push both parts separately to the stack
         (    #  Negate the values in the top list
          .ι  #  Interleave the two lists back together
   }          # Close the map
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 25 bytes

```
ＮθＷ⁻↨⮌υ±¹θ≔Ｅθ⊕‽θυ⭆υ⁺§+-κι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY07DoMwEET7nMKiWiumSBlRkY4ChOAEDqzAilnwj@T2zlLNFG/eTKv2065tzg0dKXZpe6MHJ6vbdzUWBbSGUoCXDggDnug5k1Siw0VHhIfk7qQUdQhmIWj1AU6JhiaPG1LEGQZN876x8kITi3tvKMIYOZaLT0r0lj/q2NCMPyjuZaHEh2nDmyrnZy5P@wc) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `N`.

```
Ｗ⁻↨⮌υ±¹θ
```

Until interpreting the reverse of the predefined empty list as base `-1` results in `N`, ...

```
≔Ｅθ⊕‽θυ
```

... assign `N` random integers in the range `1..N` to the list.

```
⭆υ⁺§+-κι
```

Output the list with `+` and `-` signs inserted as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 20 bytes

```
s+V*"+-"QOf!u-HGTQ^S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v1g7TEtJW1cp0D9NsVTXwz0kMC74/39jAA)

#### Explanation

```
s+V*"+-"QOf!u-HGTQ^SQQ    # Implicitly add QQ
                          # Implicitly assign Q = eval(input())
                   SQ     # range(1, Q+1)
                  ^  Q    # repeated cartesian product, Q times
          f               # filter over lambda T
            u-HGTQ        #   reduce T over subtraction with Q as the starting value
           !              #   true if 0
         O                # choose a random value from the list
 +V                       # vectorized addition with
   *"+-"Q                 # "+-" repeated Q times
s                         # join into one string
```

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc), <del>118</del> 112 bytes

*-6 bytes, thanks to @Arnauld*

```
i=0,s=0,a[];f(n){for(s=0;s-n;)for(i=s=0;i<n;)s+=a[i++]=(i%2*2-1)*~(rand()%n);for(i=0;i<n;)printf("%+d",a[i++]);}
```

[Try in online!](https://tio.run/##NY5BC4MwDIX/ihQKia3g3E6L/SXOQ9E5cjAb1pu4v97VqYcEvsd7L@mKV9fFyK60IY1vWhpAcBneEySBQiGEG7DbkOuEwTjfsDGtA9ZVXhUXzL8weekBtSDt9sP8mVjmAZQ2vbJ7DGmNo2cBXMI/NfP4hBKPpMyZuCtJfUvLGFzOCnG6v2fKbifSj3TqD1Gpco0/)

Comment: [108 bytes](https://tio.run/##NY5BC4MwDIX/ihQKia3g3C4u9pc4D0XnyMFsWG/i/npXHV7CS3jfe@mLV9/HyDZY39Z1RyMIruN7BmIXCiHcdZKuJG7SGozzLRvTOWBd5VVxwfwLs5cBUAvSgQZ3eD8zyzKC0mZQ9k8hbXHyLIBrOKCFpyeU@AeTPRN3JWluaRiD6xkhTg/3TNm9IX1I5/0hKkVu8Qc "C (gcc) – Try It Online")